# German text not displaying correctly in Outlook desktop version (vCard)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, vcf-vcard

I have a PHP function that generates vCard data from the WordPress ACF plugin. The German text is not displaying correctly in Outlook's desktop version, but it works fine on the mobile version. Here's the code I'm using to generate the vCard:

```
    function generate_vcard($post_id) {
    // Get ACF field values for the post
    $title = utf8_encode(get_field('title', $post_id));
    $first_name = utf8_encode(get_field('first_name', $post_id));
    $last_name = utf8_encode(get_field('last_name', $post_id));
    $position = utf8_encode(get_field('position', $post_id));
    $company = utf8_encode(get_field('company', $post_id));
    $birthday = utf8_encode(get_field('birthday', $post_id));
    $office_phone = utf8_encode(get_field('office_phone', $post_id));
    $cell_phone = utf8_encode(get_field('cell_phone', $post_id));
    $email_1 = utf8_encode(get_field('email_1', $post_id));
    $email_2 = utf8_encode(get_field('email_2', $post_id));
    $website = utf8_encode(get_field('website', $post_id));

    // Get profile image URL from ACF field
    $profile_image = get_field('profile_image', $post_id);

    // Encode the image to base64
    $image_data = file_get_contents($profile_image);
    $base64_image = base64_encode($image_data);

    // Generate vCard content
    $vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
    $vcard .= "VERSION:3.0\r\n";
    $vcard .= "PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=b;VALUE=URL:$base64_image\r\n";
    $vcard .= "FN:$first_name $last_name\r\n";
    $vcard .= "N:$last_name;$first_name;;;\r\n";
    $vcard .= "ORG;CHARSET=windows-1252:$company\r\n";
    $vcard .= "TITLE:$position\r\n";
    $vcard .= "BDAY:$birthday\r\n";
    $vcard .= "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:$office_phone\r\n";
    $vcard .= "TEL;TYPE=CELL,VOICE:$cell_phone\r\n";
    $vcard .= "EMAIL:$email_1\r\n";
    $vcard .= "EMAIL:$email_2\r\n";
    $vcard .= "URL:$website\r\n";
    $vcard .= "END:VCARD\r\n";

    // Set headers to trigger download with Windows-1252 encoding
    header("Content-Type: text/vcard; charset=windows-1252");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contact.vcf; charset=windows-1252");

    // Output vCard content with Windows-1252 encoding
    echo $vcard;
    exit;
}

add_action('wp', 'export_vcard');
function export_vcard() {
    if (isset($_GET['export_vcard']) && $_GET['export_vcard'] == 1) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        generate_vcard($post_id);
    }
}
```

I meant that the German text in the vCard is not rendering as expected in Outlook's desktop version. the German text appears `fÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â¼r` but the actual text is `für`.

[image]

I have tried changing the encoding of the vCard file to UTF-8, but that did not fix the problem.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Define "not displaying correctly" ? What exactly is being displayed and what exactly should be displayed?

Comment: Stop using `Windows-1252` and do what everyone else does and use full (4 byte) **UTF-8** .

Comment: I can't speak to your problem, but `utf8_encode` was [deprecated in PHP 8.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf8_decode_and_utf8_encode) because it rarely did what people thought it did, so I'd recommend just forgetting it even exists.

Comment: @sobuzislam Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is using `utf8mb4` by default, so you **must not** use `utf8_encode` on `get_field` as this will result in double-encoding. Stay with utf-8 (it's the recommended default for vCard 3.0 and a must for vCard 4.0) when creating the vCard and setting the headers. Do not add a BOM. Use `utf-8` in all lower case, as some versions of Outlook do not accept in all upper case.

Create a minimum reproducible example an then go from there. I've tested with:

```php
<?php

// Sample data
$first_name = 'Björn';
$last_name = 'Ängstler';
$company = 'Arzt für innere Medizin';

// Create vCard
$vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
$vcard .= "VERSION:3.0\r\n";
$vcard .= "FN;CHARSET=utf-8:$first_name $last_name\r\n";
$vcard .= "N;CHARSET=utf-8:$last_name;$first_name;;;\r\n";
$vcard .= "ORG;CHARSET=utf-8:$company\r\n";
$vcard .= "END:VCARD\r\n";

// Set headers to trigger download
header("Content-Type: text/vcard; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contact.vcf; charset=utf-8");

// Output vCard content
die($vcard);
```

and this imports just fine. If you still encounter problems thereafter, export a vCard from the client in question (e.g. Outlook) and open both the export and your vCard in a **text editor** to compare them.